# how to know Value of pointer (xcode) without NSLog?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, nslog

[image]

that mean makeUrlforGetBusinessIDLocal is NSString *

I want to know the value of that. without NSLog

how can I know that value? the value is http://isi............

if I do right click and choose edit value, I just can see "0x754cf40"

as we know "0x754cf40" is memory address. I don't want to know it, but the value of that memory address. how can I do that?

Can I do that without NSLog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not be aware that you can type commands into the debugger console to inspect memory locations.

So, if the pointer you want to view is at address `0x754cf40`, you would just type:

```
po [0x754cf40 description]
```

..into the console. The console is to the *right* of the variable panel you screen captured above.

Comment: You kidding me? There has to be a better way. Something I can do without touching keyboard. Anyway, best answer so far. LOL :)

Comment: Alas, debugging does sometimes involve the keyboard...I think an equal number of developers would be outraged if a debugging feature only existed through a GUI and couldn't be invoked via the console!

Comment: I can also do po makeUrlforGetBusinessIDLocal

Comment: Yes - `po` stands for "print object", so it will print any pointer or object. You use `print` for primitives, should you need to log them.